# How to use IOS and Android Native functions

Tags: xamarin, mobile

I'm totally new on mobile development especially with Xamarin language, I have for small project to create a wifi scanner App and I was wondering how to deal with Android / IOS differences, for exemple, I would like to scan available wifi when clicking on a button, how can I set the Android scan logic and the IOS logic ? I'm using Xamarin.Form.Xaml

Comment: Introduction to DependencyService : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: As @SushiHangover mentioned. DependencyService is the way to go forward with it.